Using gsub to remove specific characters([ and ]) in R
I want to remove '[' and ']' from the string.
When I use gsub("\\[|\\]", "", str), it works properly;
but when I use gsub("[\\[\\]]", "", str), it doesn't work properly.
Why?
Thank you for any help!
enter image description here
enter image description here

The [ ] character set works in a particular way. Try gsub("[][]", "", str)

I'd answer but I don't understand the ins and outs of why this works exactly, just that it works!

From ?regex: "Most metacharacters lose their special meaning inside a character class. To include a literal ‘⁠]⁠’, place it first in the list."
